# How to access contacts and show in a listview in Xamarin Forms Cross Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to access to contact list in Xamarin Forms Application but I couldnot. I searched on the internet and I tried to work some sample project they also didnot work because all sample project are old. Even I gave write and read permission it didnot work it still gave me permission error. I think Xamarin changed something in forms if you know how can I access to contact list please tell me .

I use Visual Studio 2017 and last forms version.

thanks

Comment: you would need to do this in platform specific code and call it from forms using DI

Comment: Any suggested Sample code?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/contentproviders/read_contacts/  https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/contacts/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ContactsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ContactsPlugin) which is a cross platform plugin to get Contacts from the device.

```
if(await CrossContacts.Current.RequestPermission())
 {

    List<Contact> contacts = null;
    CrossContacts.Current.PreferContactAggregation = false;
    await Task.Run(() =>
     {
       if(CrossContacts.Current.Contacts == null)
          return;

          contacts = CrossContacts.Current.Contacts
            .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.LastName) && c.Phones.Count > 0)         
            .ToList();

          contacts = contacts.OrderBy(c => c.LastName).ToList();
     });
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately,the Contacts Plugin is now marked as "THIS PLUGIN IS NOT UNDER DEVELOPMENT AND NOT SUPPORTED" (their caps, not mine).